# How to get large data via mongoose non-blocking?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, blocking, nonblocking

how do I get a large collection via mongoose a way, that I get every document returned, not a huge array with the whole collection?

At the moment I am just using following query:

```
var query = templateData.find({});
query.exec(function (err, docs) {
    // docs as array
});
```

This way, the query function is something like blocking IO and not non-blocking. Is there a way to make this more non-blocking?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, since I took another look at the mongoose documentation *after* posting this question, I got over the `stream()` function, which fullfills non-blocking operations perfectly.

Blame me, but I think it could be mentioned a bit more offensive in the mongoose documentation:
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-stream

```
var query = templateData.find({}).stream();
query.on('data', function (doc) {
    // do something with the mongoose document
}).on('error', function (err) {
    // handle the error
}).on('close', function () {
    // the stream is closed
});
```

Comment: This still blocks the main event loop for me. ~500ms on a collection with 500,000 records.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the new standard may be to use [cursors](http://thecodebarbarian.com/cursors-in-mongoose-45).